# No element found using locator: by.model() error

Tags: protractor

I'm writing an end to end test using protractor for my application. I'm seeing errors of the form:

```
No element found using locator: By.model("address.fullName") error.
```

The corresponding protractor code which is throwing this error is:

```
var angularElement = element(By.model("address.fullName"));
angularElement.sendKeys("test");
```

However I'm able to fetch this element using:

```
var angularElement = element(By.xpath('//input[@ng-model="address.fullName"]'));
```

HTML snippet:

input ng-model="address.fullName" type="text" class="control-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" size="40" name="fullName" ng-class="{ 'required-field': isInformationSubmitted }" required=""

I'm not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you put a snippet of the view? How does the HTML looks like?

Comment: Internally, I think the `By.model` locator relies on the element having the `ng-binding` class applied to it. This class is supposed to be applied automatically by angular, but I've seen instances where it didn't happen ([example](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/157)). Check if the element you're trying to locate has the `ng-binding` class or not. If not... I would *not* recommend putting it in yourself, but rather simply switching to a different locator (xpath or css) until the underlying issue in angular is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I've had some close errors, my error occurred cause the item was not shown on the page or  protractor did not finish updating its model so before using the variable i:

-maximized the page: If the element was unseen
 `browser.manage().window().maximize();`
-opened the list the item was in: 

-waiting for protractor to finish updating it's model:

```
var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.waitForAngular();
```

Comment: Since 1.5.0 it would be `browser.waitForAngular` - https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.waitForAngular