# Expected conditions in protractor

Tags: python, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

While writing selenium tests in Python, I got used to using [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html) a lot for waiting for a page to load, or for waiting for an element to become visible, or clickable etc:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
)
```

The key concept here is providing an *Expected Condition* to wait for, there are multiple types:

- [`text_to_be_present_in_element_value`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.text_to_be_present_in_element_value)
- [`element_to_be_clickable`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable)
- [`alert_is_present`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.alert_is_present)
- etc

Using Expected Conditions makes the code cleaner and more reliable comparing to using `sleep`s with hardcoded time intervals.

Now, we are switching our end-to-end testing infrastructure to `protractor` a lot.

Are there similar `Expected Conditions` in protractor as there are in [`python-selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) or 
[`java-selenium`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)? If not, what is the canonical way to explicitly wait for a condition in `protractor`?

<sup>I've looked through [protractor documentation](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) and found nothing about it.</sup>

Comment: Is this what you want? https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1703

Comment: @hankduan only if the build would not fail :) Joking, exactly, super awesome! If you have time - please post an answer about the feature here, if not - I can do it istead, lmk. Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Once [feat(expectedConditions)](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1703) is in (probably protractor 1.7), you can do:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var e = element(by.id('xyz'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(e), 10000);
expect(e.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

Please note though, if you're working with an Angular app and your test requires these conditional waits, it's a big red flag for what you're doing, as protractor should handle waits natively.

Comment: Regarding your last comment about the red flag..how would you wait for an element to be not clickable (=disabled or invisible) currently in protractor 1.5? Thank you.

Comment: Ideally, when your page settles (i.e. waitForAngular finishes as part of protractor), nothing in your page should change. (i.e. your element will either be clickable or not, and waiting will not cause its state to change). I know there are cases where this is not true, like certain animations and when setTimeout is involved (although ideally, you want to replace setTimeout with interval service). So yes there are cases where you have to add waits even for angular apps, but most of the time, it's an error in the test.

Comment: @hankduan: It seems that our tests fail frequently without these expected conditions (pure angular app). Sometimes even with. I wonder if anyone else is experiencing this kind of inconsistency.

Comment: @VSO I found sometimes animations contribute to this - protractor may think an element is clickable according to the EC, but somehow an ongoing animation / css transition blocks this. I've got a possible solution recently posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32264842/446030

Comment: To my experience, a `browser.wait(//protractor.ExpectedConditions)` is needed [when an action triggers a non-Angular async task](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/909), like a full page to be loaded. Maybe it's also (only?) required [when it triggers a route change](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2358).

Answer (score 1):

In Protractor you can use [`browser.wait(fn, timeout)`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait).

Example:

```
var element = by.id('myDynamicElement');
browser.wait(function() {
  return ptor.isElementPresent(element);
}, 10000);

expect(ptor.isElementPresent(element)).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is it, though I'm really missing all the expected conditions - shortcuts provided by other selenium language bindings. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, I've created a github issue on protractor's issue tracker: [Expected conditions in protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1681).

Comment: The current version (2.0.0 in this moment) supports: browser.wait(fn, timeout, errorMessage). Helpful to add a specific error message.

Answer (score -1):

```
waitForControlVisible(locator: string, timeout: number) {
    try {
        const element = this.findElement(locator);
        const condition = browser.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(condition.visibilityOf(element), timeout);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
        console.error('Control not visible.', e);
    }
}
```

Maybe help you, wait for element visibility in DOM.