# tell Protractor to wait for the page before executing expect

Tags: angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor, e2e-testing

When I click the export button, it makes a REST call to our endpoint then few seconds after, I receive the response then I also render the table. Unfortunately, I read that every call is asynchronous which means my expect will be executed even if table hasn't been rendered yet. The expect I wrote checks if the string is on the table but it's failing since it's not there yet. What is the proper approach to this?

```
it('should generate global user report', function() {
    element(by.css('button#exportButton')).click();

    expect(element(by.css("th[name*=Date]")).getText()).
        toEqual('Date');
})
```

The error on the console is

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("th[name*=Date]")
```

I noticed that the table hasn't been rendered yet that's why it's failing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Protractor 1.7 introduced a feature called ["Expected Conditions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737333/expected-conditions-in-protractor), that can be applied here.

Wait for element to *become visible*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.css("th[name*=Date]"));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elm), 5000);
expect(elm.getText()).toEqual('Date');
```

Comment: Cool! I'm going to try it now. Thanks!

Comment: Got an error - TypeError: Cannot call method 'visibilityOf' of undefined. I ran protractor --version and got 1.3.1 Looks like I need to update my protractor binary. Correct?

Comment: @devwannabe correct, 1.3.1 is way too old anyway :)

Comment: The only right answer relevant to newer versions at time of writing this comment 5/5/2015. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had problem waiting for a dynamic element to appear.  Have the driver wait for it to either be present or displayed.  The number at the end is the timeout.

```
element(by.css('button#exportButton')).click();
var header = element(by.css("th[name*=Date]"));
browser.driver.wait(function() {
    return header.isPresent();
}, 1000);
expect(header.getText()).toEqual('Date');
```

I had to wait until it was present AND displayed before the test was fully stable.  You can do that like this:

```
var header = element(by.css("th[name*=Date]"));        
browser.driver.wait(function() {
    return header.isPresent().then(function(present) {
        if (present) {
            return header.isDisplayed().then(function(visible) {                   
                return visible;
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I'll try your solution to later once I get off the train. The update of protractor to 1.8 also worked with the poster's code above. I'll your code too because of the use of 'then'

Comment: It worked too using my old protractor! Thanks Alan Yackel! :)