# protractor serial spec execution

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I faced with strange problem after my tests refactor. I deprecated everywhere beforeEach/afterEach blocks in order to significantly decrease execution time and now I have problems to run even simple specs one after another. I have create simple config and specs.

Config:

```
 exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: [
        'googleSpec.js',
        'forgotPasswordPageTestSuite.js'
        ],
    capabilities:
    {
        browserName: 'chrome'
        //shardTestFiles: true,
        //maxInstances: 2
    },
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000
    }
}
```

Spec 1:

```
describe("Google Spec", function()
{

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('http://google.com');

    browser.wait(function () {
        return element(by.name('q')).isDisplayed();
    }, 15000);

    it('Verify search inout is presented', function()
    {
        expect(browser.isElementPresent(element(by.name('q'))).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Spec 2:

```
describe("Yandex spec", function()
{
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('http://www.yandex.ru');

    browser.wait(function () {
             return element(by.id('text')).isDisplayed();
        }, 15000);
    });

    it('Verify that search input is presented', function()
    {
        expect(browser.isElementPresent(by.id('text'))).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

If I execute them separately of using

```
shardTestFiles: true,
maxInstances: 2
```

it is just ok, but when I have above config I have such exception:

> [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver F.
>
> Failures:
>
> 1) Google Spec Verify search inout is presented    Message:
>        Expected false to be true.    Stacktrace:
>        Error: Failed expectation
>       at [object Object]. (/Users/sergeyteplyakov/WebstormProjects/e2eMPP20/googleSpec.js:13:54)
>
> Finished in 6.339 seconds 2 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failure
>
> [launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running [launcher] chrome
>
> ## 1 failed 1 test(s) [launcher] overall: 1 failed spec(s) [launcher] Process exited with error code 1
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

In my real tests I have the same issue, when my spec is similar to what I have provided. When I look what is really happening for some reason .get(url) method from 2nd spec started executing before 1st spec is getting finished. I guess I am missing something core and significant, could anyone point me please)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that with this setup there is no guarantee that `protractor` would perform that `wait()` call and wait for the results before executing `it()`.

If you want some code being executed before all of the `it` blocks in the spec, use `beforeAll()` (built-in in Jasmine 2, available as a [third-party](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll) for Jasmine 1.x):

```
describe("Google Spec", function()
{
    beforeAll(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get('http://google.com');

        browser.wait(function () {
            return element(by.name('q')).isDisplayed();
        }, 15000);
    });

    it('Verify search inout is presented', function()
    {
        expect(browser.isElementPresent(element(by.name('q'))).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Also note that you can use [Expected Conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737333/expected-conditions-in-protractor) to simplify that `wait()` block:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var elm = element(by.name('q'));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elm), 15000);
```

Comment: I tried to include beforeAll blocks, but they have not helped. Also when in my real test I just put in the 2nd suite all code before 1st 'it' block in beforeEach it start working, this is really weird

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov thanks, what if you move `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` to `onPrepare()`?