# Protractor did not run properly when using browser.wait, msg: "Wait timed out after XXXms"

Tags: python, django, protractor, end-to-end, e2e-testing

I used protractor a long time, install django and update python in Mac OS X (Mavericks), after this:

```
browser.wait(function(){ element.isPresent() });
```

does not work properly and show the message above:

```
Message:

    Error: Wait timed out after 270ms

   Stacktrace:

    Error: Wait timed out after 270ms
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at runMicrotasksCallback (node.js:337:7)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

From: Task: < anonymous wait >
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one problem with your custom wait function is that you don't have a `return`. But, anyway, there is a [`presenceOf`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf) built-in [`ExpectedCondition`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737333/expected-conditions-in-protractor) that fits your use case:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element), 5000);
```

Comment: Hi Alecxe, this wait.browser does not work correctly in parts of the page that does not have angularJS, for instance slickgrid, about the question, it's my mistake I used: browser.wait(function(){ return element.isPresent().then(function(show){ if (show){} return element.isDisplayed(); }); });    -----> I do not know why this code broken when I updated protractor and selenium webdriver. Thank's.