# How to upload files in filepicker using protractor?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

[image]

Here is HTML code:

```
<input type="file" class="fileUploadInput" name="fileUpload" id="fileUploadInput" accept="application/msword,application/pdf,text/plain,application/rtf,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula" multiple="multiple" title="Choose File">
```

Here is my code:

```
 browser.wait(function(){
            return element(by.id('.filepicker_dialog_container')).isPresent();
        }).then(function() {
            browser.driver.switchTo().frame('.filepicker_dialog');
        }).then(function(){
            var fileToUpload = '/home/raghavendra/Desktop/f0657c76d96b9ddab5562b8391297dbbb01488fec4e79a4c13195aea.doc';
            var absolutePath = protractor.basePath.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
            $("#fileUploadInput").sendKeys(absolutePath);
});
```

I am doing like this, now am not getting any error but it is not uploading the file. The pop up window is not closing now.

Here is my complete code:

```
  var path = require('path');
var ptor = browser,
    driver = browser.driver;

describe('Hirealchemy roles', function() {

    it('while clicking filepicker icon', function () {


        $('.icon-people').click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
        browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/ng-view/div/div/div[2]/' +
                                            'section/div/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/input')).sendKeys(group_name);
        browser.sleep(5000);
        element.all(by.css('.btn.btn-main')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);

        browser.wait(function(){
             return element(by.id('filepicker_dialog')).isPresent();
        })
            .then(function(){
                ptor.switchTo().frame('filepicker_dialog');
            })

            .then(function(){
                 var fileToUpload = '/home/raghavendra/Desktop/50_resumes/f0657c76d96b9ddab5562b8391297dbbb01488fec4e79a4c13195aea.doc';
                 var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
                 driver.findElement(By.id('fileUploadInput')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
            })

            .then(function(){
                ptor.switchTo().defaultContent();
            })

            .then(function(){
                browser.wait(function(){
                    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
                    element(by.id('filepicker_dialog')).isPresent()
                        .then(function(present){
                            deferred.fulfill(!present);
                        });
                    return deferred.promise;

                });
            });
    });
})
```

This code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working:

```
var path = require('path');
var ptor = browser,
    driver = browser.driver;

describe('Hirealchemy roles', function() {

    it('while clicking filepicker icon', function () {


        $('.icon-people').click();
        browser.sleep(5000);
        browser.driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/ng-view/div/div/div[2]/' +
                                            'section/div/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/input')).sendKeys(group_name);
        browser.sleep(5000);
        element.all(by.css('.btn.btn-main')).click();
        browser.sleep(5000);

        browser.wait(function(){
             return element(by.id('filepicker_dialog')).isPresent();
        })
            .then(function(){
                ptor.switchTo().frame('filepicker_dialog');
            })

            .then(function(){
                 var fileToUpload = '/home/raghavendra/Desktop/50_resumes/f0657c76d96b9ddab5562b8391297dbbb01488fec4e79a4c13195aea.doc';
                 var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
                 driver.findElement(By.id('fileUploadInput')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
            })

            .then(function(){
                ptor.switchTo().defaultContent();
            })

            .then(function(){
                browser.wait(function(){
                    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
                    element(by.id('filepicker_dialog')).isPresent()
                        .then(function(present){
                            deferred.fulfill(!present);
                        });
                    return deferred.promise;

                });
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't click the "Choose File" button. When you click it, a browser's Select File dialog would appear. *You would not be able to control this dialog* since it is out of selenium webdriver's scope.

Instead, *send the keys to the input with an absolute path to the file to upload*:

```
$("#fileUploadInput").sendKeys("/absolute/path/to/file");
```

---

In your particular case, do:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var picker = element(by.id('.filepicker_dialog_container'));

browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(picker), 5000);
browser.switchTo().frame($('.filepicker_dialog'));

var fileToUpload = '/home/raghavendra/Desktop/f0657c76d96b9ddab5562b8391297dbbb01488fec4e79a4c13195aea.doc';
var absolutePath = protractor.basePath.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
$("#fileUploadInput").sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

Comment: I am getting this error: NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("#fileUploadInput")

Comment: @raghavendrat from what I understand, this is usually because of two things - the button is inside an iframe and you need to switch to it before searching for the element and/or you need to wait for the element to become present: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27867319/771848. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have posted my code, please have a look and guide me where am doing wrong.

Comment: Now am getting this error :   RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: @raghavendrat how about `browser.driver.switchTo().frame($('.filepicker_dialog'));`?

Comment: @raghavendrat is this a public site and you can share a link to it?

Comment: @raghavendrat also, what protractor version are you using? If you are not using the latest protractor, consider upgrading. Also try `browser.driver.switchTo().frame($('.filepicker_dialog').getWebElement());`

Comment: No it's private..I am using protractor version 2.5.1.

Comment: @raghavendrat do you see the same error after upgrading to protractor 3? Please also try: `browser.driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(by.css('.filepicker_dialog')));`.

Comment: I upgraded and still am not able to..please help me

Comment: @raghavendrat what about the `browser.driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(by.css('.filepicker_dialog')‌​));`?

Comment: Now am getting this error: Error: Wait timed out after 5006ms

Comment: @raghavendrat could you please edit the question and include the complete code you have so far and the complete traceback? This would help to help. The idea presented in the answer is still valid for file uploads in general, we just need to make it work in your case. It's like a guessing game unfortunately, but let's see what you've got at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: @raghavendrat could you please remove the `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(picker), 5000);` line and try again?

Comment: Finally it worked....I have done some modifications and now am able to upload files...Thank u so much...I have posted my updated code...please have a look

Comment: Please help me out of this question also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35715973/not-able-to-click-on-hidden-element-in-protractorplease-go-through-the-image