# ScriptTimeoutError with Angular/Protractor test suite

Tags: angular, protractor

I am using Protractor to test automate with Angular web application. My test suite has around 37 test cases. Each test case runs successfully when it runs individually.When I run the whole test suite, I get

> ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout
>   .......................................
>   From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(xpath, /html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/div[2]/as-split/as-split-area[2]/app-tabhost/app-tab[1]/div/app-files/div/div[2]/ag-grid-angular/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[12]/div[1]])

most of the time.

I have followed few solutions, but they didn't work.

1. browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
2. browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element), 10000)

I have posted relevant code snippets to understand the issue. Is there any wrong?

- Angular version - 7.2.16
- Protractor version - 5.4.4

**Component_spec.js**

```
var LoginModule = require("./LoginModule.js");
var ComponentModule = require("./ComponentModule.js");

describe('Component Spec', function () {
var componentModule = new ComponentModule();

beforeAll(async function () {
    console.log("===Loading home page");
    browser.driver.sleep(8000);
});

beforeEach(async function () {
    browser.get(LoginModule.homeUrl);
    browser.driver.sleep(8000);
});

it('editinput', async function () {
    var AlertMessage = element(by.cssContainingText('.col-sm-11', 'underline'));
    componentModule.editinput("value");
    expect(AlertMessage.isPresent()).toBe(false);
    browser.driver.sleep(5000);
});
});
```

**ComponentModule.js**

```
this.editinput = async function (value) {
    let selectCheckbox2 = element(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/div[2]/as-split/as-split-area[2]/app-tabhost/app-tab[1]/div/app-files/div/div[2]/ag-grid-angular/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[12]/div[1]'));
    await selectCheckbox2.click();
    await browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    let selectNext = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="next"]'));
    await selectNext.click();
    await browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    let input = element(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/div[2]/as-split/as-split-area[2]/app-tabhost/app-tab[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button[2]'))
    await input.click();

    let right = element(by.className("right_button"));
    await right.click();
    await browser.driver.sleep(2000);

    let edit = element(by.className("edit_box"));
    await edit.sendKeys(value);
    await browser.driver.sleep(5000);

    let saveBtn = element(by.xpath('/html/body/app-root/app-home/div/div/div[2]/as-split/as-split-area[2]/app-tabhost/app-tab[2]/div/app-procedure/div/div[2]/div[1]/button[3]/i'));
    await saveBtn.click();
    await browser.driver.sleep(8000);
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
};
```

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
   framework: 'jasmine',
   seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

   capabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      acceptSslCerts: true,
      shardTestFiles: false,
      maxInstances: 1
   },
   jasmineNodeOpts: {
      showColors: true,
      defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000,
   },
   onPrepare: () => {
      browser.manage().window().maximize();
      browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

It not good automation test practise to use `browser.driver.sleep(5000);` after each step. So try to remove `browser.driver.sleep(5000);` from beforeAll, beforeEach and after clicking element. Always try to use minimum sleep as possible if required.

Use Expected conditions[Here]:https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions instead using sleep.

conf.js changes.

```
directConnect: true,
allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
```

Check [Here]:https://www.protractortest.org/#/server-setup

Use Minimum implicitlyWait

```
 browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500);
```

Comment: Even individual test case didn't work,  when I used expected conditions instead of sleep. That's why I have used sleep in order to successfully run the test case. Do you have an idea why is that expected conditions didn't work?

Comment: you can check  [link1]https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions   or [link2]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737333/expected-conditions-in-protractor