# How to have protractor reliable results?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm using Protractor (v 1.3.1) to run E2E tests for my Angular 1.2.26 application.

But sometimes, tests are ok, sometimes not. It seems that sometimes the check is done before display is updated (or something like "synchronisation" problem).
I try many options :

- add `browser.driver.sleep` instructions,
- disable effects with `browser.executeScript('$.fx.off = true')`
- add `browser.waitForAngular()` instructions

without success.

What are the bests practice to have reliables E2E tests with protractor?

JM.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every time I have similar issues, I'm using [`browser.wait()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) with ["Expected Conditions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737333/expected-conditions-in-protractor) ([introduced in protractor 1.7](https://github.com/angular/protractor/pull/1703)). There is a set of built-in expected conditions that is usually enough, but you can easily define your custom expected conditions.

For example, waiting for an *element to become visible*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var e = element(by.id('xyz'));

browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(e), 10000);
expect(e.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
```

Few notes:

- you can specify a custom error message in case the conditions would not be met and a timeout error would be thrown, see [Custom message on wait timeout error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28979368/custom-message-on-wait-timeout-error):

  ```
  browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(e), 10000, "Element 'xyz' has not become visible");
  ```
- you can set `EC` to be a globally available variable pointing to `protractor.ExpectedConditions`. Add this line to the `onPrepare()` in your config:

  ```
  onPrepare: function () {
      global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
  }
  ```
- as an example of a custom expected condition, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28893283/771848)

Comment: Thank's for this solution ! I will try this but I have to update my Protractor version. I'll keep you in touch

Answer (score 2):

Another point which is very important in testing with Protractor is understanding the ControlFlow. You may find explaination and code example here : [When should we use .then with Protractor Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331499/when-should-we-use-then-with-protractor-promise)

Jean-marc

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to consider.

The first is that you should properly sequence all protractor actions (as also hinted by @jmcollin92). For this, I typically use `.then` on *every* step.

The second important thing is to make sure that a new test `it(...)` only starts after the previous `it(...)` has completed.

If you use the latest version of Protractor, you can use Jasmine 2.x and its support for signalling the completion of a test:

```
it('should do something', function(done) {
   clicksomething().then(function() {
     expect(...);
     done();
   });
});
```

Here the `done` argument is invoked to signal that the test is ready. Without this, Protractor will *schedule* the `clicksomething` command, and then immediately move on with the next test, returning to the present test only once `clicksomething` has completed.

Since typically both tests inspect and possibly modify the same browser/page, your tests become unpredictable if you let them happen concurrently (one test clicks to the next page, while another is still inspecting the previous page).

If you use an earlier version of Protractor (1.3 as you indicate), the Jasmine 1.3 `runs` and `waitsFor` functions can be used to simulate this behavior.

Note that the whole point of using Protractor is that Protractor is supposed to know when Angular is finished. So in principle, there should be no need to ever call `waitForAngular` (my own test suite with dozens of scenarios does not include a single wait/waitForAngular). The better your application-under-test adheres to Angular's design principles, the fewer `WaitForAngular`'s you should need.

Comment: Very interesting ! I'm using Mocha and I guess the done principle explains here is valid for Mocha.

Comment: Yes. Haven't used Mocha myself, but I think Jasmine 2.x took the `done` approach from Mocha.

Answer (score 1):

I would add that disabling ngAnimate may not be enough. You may also have to disable all transition animation by injecting CSS ([What is the cleanest way to disable CSS transition effects temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131875/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-disable-css-transition-effects-temporarily)).