# Need browser url substring inside function

Tags: javascript, protractor, angular-promise, webdriverjs

I am working on angular app automation where I have written a common function which needs to called at multiple places in my tests to get the form id which is generating dynamically. This function is always returning me {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}"] error.

> CommonFunctions.js

```
var common_functions = function() {    
this.getFormId = function() {
   //  var url = "http://localhost/test/#/submission/207/form/1976";
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
        return url.substr(-4);
    });

   }  
};
```

Now this function is being used in pageobject file to get the element locator.

> PageObject file:

```
var general_information = function() {
        this.street1 = function(field1) {
        var formid = common_functions.getFormId();
        var street="fieldValue.street1_".concat(formid);
        element(by.model(street)).sendKeys(field1);
    }
```

Finally when i invoke this function in my test script, I get error.

> Test script:

```
it("Verify that user is able to fill values in general information", function(){

        general_information.street1('Street Victoria');
        general_information.zipCode('1004');

    });
```

> Exception appearing:

```
Failed: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[ng-model="fieldValue.street1_Promise::1833 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}"]' is not a valid selector.
   (Session info: chrome=50.0.2661.94)
   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

Can somebody help me with this where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the *`getFormId()` function returns a [promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331499/when-should-we-use-then-with-protractor-promise)*. And, since you need a value into which a promise is resolved, you need to use `.then()`:

```
this.street1 = function(field1) {
    common_functions.getFormId().then(function (formid) {
        var street = "fieldValue.street1_".concat(formid);
        element(by.model(street)).sendKeys(field1);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks alecxe...This works!! I was aware somehow Promise is not getting resolved but wasn't making changes correctly!!