# Synchronization inside the 'it' Block in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Hi actually i'm facing sync in 'it' block of my code. Following snippet depicts the problem.

```
 it('Some Download Operation',function()
 {
    console.log("before");
    myobj.clickOnDownloadBtn();
    console.log("after download click");
    browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    var enter = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
    enter.perform();
    console.log("after enter btn");
});
```

Im getting the output like:

```
before
after download click
after enter btn
//Then the  click on PO Object's 'myobj.clickOnDownloadBtn()' operation.
```

Please soon let me know the problem and solution for this.

Comment: why don't you use settimeout?

Comment: not worked @AmitSoni

Answer (score 2):

You have to add then function, like this way :

```
 it('Some Download Operation',function()
 {

    myobj.clickOnDownloadBtn().then (function() {
    console.log("after enter btn");
    console.log("after download click");
    });

    browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    var enter = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
    enter.perform().then (function() {
    console.log("after enter btn");
    });

});
```

Comment: Good job! Btw, added a little bit more to "why" this would work in a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks for your encouragements alecxe ;) we are learning from your examples ;)

Comment: Thanks alecxe and Emna :)

Comment: but the Enter Key Operation didn't worked... from escaping/dowloading a file.... :(

Comment: @balu sounds like a separate problem to me. Consider creating a separate question and resolving this topic by accepting Emna's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate a little bit more to why @Emna's solution would help:

Protractor is entirely *asynchronous* and is based on the concept of promises - you cannot expect your code work from top to bottom in a blocking nature. In Protractor, there is that [Control Flow](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow) mechanism that acts as a *queue* of WebDriver promises.

To put that into the perspective of your code:

```
console.log("before");
myobj.clickOnDownloadBtn();
console.log("after download click");
browser.driver.sleep(5000);
var enter = browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
enter.perform();
console.log("after enter btn");
```

Here, everything would be executed from top to bottom, but `console.log()` calls would be performed right away, since they are synchronous. Calls like `myobj.clickOnDownloadBtn()`, `browser.driver.sleep(5000)` and `enter.perform()` return promises, would not be executed right away but would be put on the Control Flow instead. That's why you see `console.log` results before any actions are performed on the page.

Related topics:

- [Asynchronous Testing with Protractor’s ControlFlow](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/12/17/asynchronous-testing-protractor-angular/)
- [When should we use .then with Protractor Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331499/when-should-we-use-then-with-protractor-promise)

Comment: Thanks for explanation @alecxe