# Protractor tests complete with Chrome / Firefox but fail in phantomjs

Tags: angularjs, selenium, phantomjs, protractor

I have written a fair amount of E2E tests using protractor running firefox and chrome and all works well, however when I try to use phantomjs so that we can get them running on our CI server they fail with the line:

```
UnknownError: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'
System info: host: 'referenemesimac.home', ip: '192.168.1.67', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.4', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
```

Has anyone come into this before? Here is my protractor.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  // The address of a running selenium server.
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'phantomjs'
  },

  onPrepare: function () {
    var width = 1440;
    var height = 900;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
  },

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directly when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['protractor_specs/**/*.js'],

  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000',

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },

};
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/557#issuecomment-55373851):

you should use **ignoreSynchronization** browser's option and **sleep()** method of protractor to make it work, like that:

```
//
// test/e2e/base/registration.js
//
'use strict';
var $p;

describe('E2E Registration', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    $p = protractor.getInstance();
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
  });

  it('should register a user', function() {
    browser.get('/#/register');
    $p.sleep(3000);
    expect(element(by.css('input.sign-up-button')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
    element(by.model('user.email')).sendKeys('foo@bar.it');
    element(by.model('user.password')).sendKeys('bar');
    element(by.model('user.repeatPassword')).sendKeys('bar');
    element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'ITALY')).click();
    element(by.css('ins.iCheck-helper')).click();
    element(by.css('input.sign-up-button')).click();
    $p.sleep(3000);
    expect($p.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch(/dashboard/i);
  });
});
```

Yes, I don't like it, but it works.

Hope someone will answer this question better.

You can also try to replace **$p.sleep()** with **$p.waitForAngular();**, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24185931/801426).

Comment: We decided to drop protractor for something more stable. We are now using Capybara

Comment: Having a day getting all that bugs with protractor and phantomjs after several months, when all that tests worked, I start thinking the same.